# Prevent the Siri Watch Face from displaying Photo Memories

Tags: notifications, photos.app, apple-watch, siri, watchos

The Siri Watch Face, introduced with watchOS 4, automatically suggests content, including "Photo Memories" from the iOS Photos app.

I'm not keen on having year-old photos on my wrist, I much prefer stuff that actually are day-to-day relevant there.

I've tried to get rid of these Photo Memory items, but haven't succeeded:

- Turned off Photos notifications in the "Watch" app.
- Turned off Photos notifications in the iOS Notifications settings.
- Watched the "Memory", did not help.
- Deleting the "Memory" helped getting rid of it, but a day later I get a new one.

Help! I *really* don't need to see some random old party pics with people I don't even know that well, as opposed to upcoming calendar items, alarms, stocks, or whatever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Photo Memories, along with other "Data Sources" for the Siri Watch Face, can be turned off in the *Watch* app on iOS.

*Watch app > My Watch > My Faces > Siri (Watch Face) > Data Sources*

You can also turn off Breathe, Home, Stocks, etc.

Comment: There is no "Data Sources" item available at that location, at least as of watchOS 6.1

Answer (score 4):

The location seems to have changed in later versions of iOS. You need to change the Data Sources for the Siri Watch Face. It can be changed in the Watch App on your iPhone.

Watch app > My Watch > Notifications > Clock > Siri Face Data Sources

Turn off Photos. You can turn off many other Data Sources as well.